# Pip is not linking to my upgraded Python version. Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: linux, pip

Having issues linking pip to **Python 3.7**. Both `pip` and `pip3` been installed but linking to **Python 2.7**.

I have tried to reinstall **Python3** and then `pip` no progress.

I get the following message:

> Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

```bash
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4

$ pip -V
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
pip 19.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip3 -V
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
pip 19.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)


$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
[sudo] password for TarikDev: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: The link between `python` and `pip` is in [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: To fix package 'python3-pip' you probably need to change apt mirror and update: `sudo apt update`. May be just update would be enough.

Comment: @phd I did and it fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First use this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Two packages will be downloaded, of size 16 MB. Then:

```
sudo apt-get install python2-pip
```

Answer (score 14):

I tried this and it worked for me:

```bash
# Download current package information.
sudo apt-get update.

# Install a new package.
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

# Test the package install.
pip -V
```

Answer (score 1):

go to your sources.list file with the following steps:

```sh
cd /etc/apt
sudo nano sources.list
```

Now edit this line in this file

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Now press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> key and then press <kbd>y</kbd> to save the buffer and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Now try `sudo apt-get update`

Now type the command `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 1):

First, update the system using the update command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install pip package to the machine,

```
sudo apt-get install python2-pip python3-pip
```

If you are still facing challenges to install pip then try the following commands:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python get-pip.py

pip -V
```